# What is the meaning of 'Well noted."?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I got a job offer and I have to attend a psychological test tomorrow, 08:30 am. I can't attend at that time so I ask for a reschedule on next Monday. The HR person replied to my email with:

> Well noted. We'll sumbit the information to our user.

I don't understand, is it a 'yes' or 'no'? Or is it meaning that the HR person will ask her boss (user) if he/she can or not?

Comment: It means that your HR has acknowledged your request. It is another way of saying duly noted (correctly or appropriately recorded). If they have the power to accept themselves, it is most likely that they agreed, if they don't, it means they are submitting your request to someone who can accept it.

Comment: Whatever the HR bureaucrat may have been meant by that phrase in this particular case, it should be observed, for the benefit of future visitors to this page, that this was not an example of good, clear, unambiguous communication. It is not an example to be emulated.

Answer (score 4):

It is a "yes".  It is both acknowledgement and assurance.

Someone might casually say, "Noted," but to say, "Well noted," or "Duly noted," is to *emphasize* that they have read your message, understood it fully, and will act according to your wishes.

Comment: Actually, *noted* does not imply that the recipient will act accordingly. The word is often used precisely to imply that one reserves the right to disagree with or reject whatever has been noted.

Comment: @jsw - That's only when sarcasm is involved, and typically it's also being used in a different manner from the one OP asked about, e.g. "Fine. Your objection is noted. Now, moving on..."